# Mock oauth Access token ( implicit grant )

Tags: javascript, oauth-2.0

**Is there a way to mock (generate valid token-object) oauth v2.0 token (implicit grant strategy) for test purposes?**

I want to unit test access-token parsing from oAuth service and would be nice to have some piece of javascript code that does something like this:

1. generate valid object
2. encode it with base64 encoding ( I think this is the one that is used )

**Or this is impossible due to some limitations?**

Answer (score 0):

**Implicit Grant - oAuth 2.0**

It turned out that I can use valid token from server response and transform it into good-for-testing one. In my case the response from oAuth server has the following form:

**header** - encoded algorithm for has creation

**access token** - base64 encoded object (encode/decode with atob()/btoa() functions on window object)

**hash** - of the 3 previous items done using algorithm specified in the header.

It has the following structure: **header.access_token.hash**

It turns out the token will not be valid without correct hash. The hashing of the token data is done in server side using private key, so if I change the hash the token will become obsolete.

As my token-parsing-function that I wanted to check uses only the access_token part of the request, I've changed the header and hash parts and also encoded other user name for sake of testing purposes.